# I am receiving 'Error in !toroidal : invalid argument type'

Tags: r

I am trying to run a supervised SOM model based on cross-validated values.

The issue seems is in the sup.som line. I receive this error: Error in !toroidal : invalid argument type.

This code has worked fine in the past (within past few days) and I have tried restarting `RStudio`. There was a very similar question here ([Error in !toroidal : invalid argument type in R with som package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424757/error-in-toroidal-invalid-argument-type-in-r-with-som-package)) but the issue seemed to have resolved itself for the other person. Any help is appreciated!

My code is:

```
require(kohonen)

set.seed(123)

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 10)

tg <- expand.grid(xdim=c(3:10), ydim=c(3:10), user.weights=seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1), topo="hexagonal")

somFit1 <- train(train[,1:6], as.factor(train$CORR), method="xyf", trControl=fitControl, tuneLength=20, tuneGrid=tg)

'''sup.som <- xyf(training.sc, classvec2classmat(corrupt.train), grid = somgrid(xdim=somFit1$bestTune$xdim, ydim=somFit1$bestTune$ydim, topo="hexagonal"), user.weights=somFit1$bestTune$user.weights, keep.data=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying my code in the R console to see if I could get more detailed error messages, and I got the following:

require(class)
Loading required package: class
Attaching package: ‘class’
The following object is masked from ‘package:kohonen’:
    somgrid

The solution was to specify kohonen::somgrid before my code as follows:

sup.som <- xyf(training.sc, classvec2classmat(corrupt.train), grid = kohonen::somgrid(xdim=somFit1$bestTune$xdim, ydim=somFit1$bestTune$ydim, topo="hexagonal"), user.weights=somFit1$bestTune$user.weights, keep.data=TRUE)

Hope this helps someone else